# Next method not executing after the main method

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I have to files out of which the first file contains login details. First file is loginDetailsClass.java and below is the code in the file.

```
public class loginDetailsClass {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void browserLaunch() {

        WebDriver driver;
        String baseurl = "https://www.facebook.com/";       
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\eclipse-workspace\\chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--test-type");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","D:\\eclipse-workspace\\chromedriver.exe");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseurl);

    //Login section
        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        } 

        WebElement usnfield = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        usnfield.sendKeys("alex");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        WebElement pwdfield = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
        pwdfield.sendKeys("alex42");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
        }
        WebElement lgn_btn = driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_8"));
        lgn_btn.click();

    }
 }
```

And the second file is facebookClass.java and below is the code in the file.

```
public class facebookClass {

    static WebDriver driver;

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        loginDetailsClass.browserLaunch(); //function called from loginDetailsClass.java page
        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    @Test(priority = 1) 
    public static void searchfriends() {


        //Switching to iFrame for locating elements
         driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("contentFrame")));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        //Searching a friend using friend name field
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 20);
        WebElement friendName = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("txtFriendName")));
        friendName.sendKeys("James");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        WebElement clck_Search = driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch"));
        clck_Search.click();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        WebElement select_friend = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"trFriend_3\"]"));
        select_friend.click();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        //Switching back to main frame from iFrame
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }


     }

     @Test(priority = 2)
     public static void logout() {

         //Logout
         WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div[8]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]"));
         logout.click();        

         try {
             Thread.sleep(7000);
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
         }
         driver.close();
         }

   }
```

While executing facebookClass.java, login method is called properly and login is successful. But from *public static void searchfriends()* method, execution doesn't works further. At the very first days all methods got executed successfully. But from the next day it now working.

Comment: `searchfriends()` is not called from anywhere, right?

Comment: searchfriends() hasen't been called.

Comment: you need to call the method for the method to *be* called.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing two patterns for execution. The `@Test` annotations are clearly intended for your testing framework to pick up, whereas the `static void Main(String[] args)` is the standard pattern for a runnable application. Perhaps in the past you were executing this program with a test runner, and today you're executing it directly as an application?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: i am using selenium Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) for running my tests every time. It's now more than a week and tried all possible things to solve it all by myself. But now seems like, i need a help.

Comment: @luk2302: it's an error as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at packages.facebookClass.main(facebookClass.java:35)" and line number 35 is "driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("contentFrame")));"